# Where does modem manager gui store sms?

Tags: linux, debian, modem, wwan

I am sending and  receiving MMS using [Modem Manager GUI](https://linuxonly.ru/page/modem-manager-gui).

I've checked everywhere, Google and documentation and I cannot find where modem manager GUI stores SMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it should be in `~/.local/share/modem-manager-gui/devices/ID/sms.gdbm`

Comment: Can you tell know how can I read / write things in `.gdbm`?

Comment: as @harrymc already replied, https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/ should be the answer

Comment: `# apt install gdbmtool`

Answer (score 2):

Modem Manager GUI creates a database named `sms.gdbm` to store all the SMS details.

[GDBM](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/)
is a simple light database, or perhaps better called "storage".
It is just basically a way to store simple key-value pairs of any kind.
It has no other structure as may be found in a traditional database,
only keys and values.

To view or export the data, you could use the tool
[gdbmtool](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-gdbmtool/).
The *gdbmtool export command* will export the database to a flat file,
and is basically equivalent to the
[gdbm_dump command](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-gdbm_dump/).

For writing your own application in C, if you are so motivated,
some starting references are:

- [How to get the structure of a GDBM database](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216941/how-to-get-the-structure-of-a-gdbm-database)
- [Lightweight databases in C : GDBM](http://jwhsmith.net/2014/03/lightweight-databases-in-c-gdbm/)

Comment: Do I need to write app in C in order to use gdbm? I was thinking of writing it in NodeJS for convenience.

Comment: No, you don't need to, if the above standard utilities are enough.